# ListViewItem custom template: ContentPresenter stays empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, listviewitem, contentpresenter

I have the following ListView in my code. `views:GameCard` is a custom `UserControl` and `{Binding}` is a valid `DataContext` object with three items. Without the custom `ItemContainerStyle` everything works perfectly — the list shows three `GameCards` with correct info, etc. As soon as I add the `ItemContainerStyle` part, I get nothing but three "ABCD"s; so the data is still loaded correctly, but my `UserControl` is no longer displayed (I only added the "ABCD" to check if the data was there, as otherwise I got nothing but empty box).

Every piece of info I could find online seems to indicate that just putting a `ContentPresenter` element in the template should work, but it doesn't seem to in this case. What am I missing?

```cs
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF614B4B" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDA7070" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ListView.Background>
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <views:GameCard />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="ABCD" />
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: try `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the [TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.targettype.aspx) of your ControlTemplate. And in order to make your ItemTemplate work, you'd also need to bind the `Content` and `ContentTemplate` properties.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        ....
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ... />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I just discovered that literally 5 seconds before reading your answer. Thanks anyway! :) The binding does not appear to be needed though, it works without it.

Comment: This works, but it loses the blue selection rectangle for the selected item... any way that can be preserved?

Comment: @FactorMystic The selection rectangle has to be part of the ListViewItem ControlTemplate (e.g. as another child element of the Grid). You may take a look at the [default ListViewItem style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) to get an idea how it could look like.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the case with you but so far I haven't had to modify the ItemContainerStyle yet, just the ListView.View. Since you're putting a Grid in your template style I'd assume you're looking for a GridView and this is how you do that:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="120">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Height="14" >
                <TextBlock Text="Type" FontSize="9"/>
            </GridViewColumnHeader>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name, FallbackValue=MISSING}" /> 
    <!-- or content presenter with bindings here -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

your style and everything is fine .All what required is to Assign or bind the **Content property** to your ContentPresenter. I hope this will help.

Comment: And `ControlTemplate` needs a `TargetType`.